# how to access data inside a component in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

Hi I want to access msg inside my template how can achieve this in vuejs? my webpack watcher is having an error " - text "{{msg}}" outside root element will be ignored."

```
    <template>
    {{msg}}
    <form action="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" v-on:submit.prevent="addPension">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">submit </button>
   </form>
   </template>

<script>
  export default {
  data: () => ({
      msg : 'new messages'
  }),
  created() 
  {

  }

  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Templates in Vue must have a `single` root element. The code in your template should look like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{msg}}
    <form action="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" v-on:submit.prevent="addPension">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">submit </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
```

Note the wrapping `div`. It doesn't have to be a `div`, but there needs to be *one* containing element.